# How to traverse typed abstract syntax tree in OCaml compiler

Tags: compiler-construction, ocaml, abstract-syntax-tree, ocamlbuild

I'm trying to dump type information of all identifiers in an OCaml project, basically it's the same as traversing the typed abstract syntax tree(https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml/blob/trunk/typing/typedtree.mli). Since I'm new to OCaml compiler's codebase, I'm not sure whether the Compiler has provided apis so we could easily write a plugin to do the job or we have to hack the compiler code? Also how does this interact with OCamlbuild? Thanks for any hints or advices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you have already got a typed AST of type `structure` somehow.

The classic way is simply to write a big recursive function to traverse the AST by yourself.

But now there is module `TypedtreeIter` available in OCaml compiler source code and it is exposed to `compiler-libs`. For simple traversal, this is very handy.

`TypedtreeIter` provides a functor to build your own iterator over typed ASTs. Here is a very simple example to print all the pattern identifiers with their types:

```
(* ocamlfind ocamlc -package compiler-libs.common -c example.ml *)
open Typedtree
open TypedtreeIter

module MyIteratorArgument = struct
  include DefaultIteratorArgument

  let enter_pattern p = match p.pat_desc with
    | Tpat_var (id, _) ->
        Format.printf "@[<2>%s@ : %a@]@."
          (Ident.name id)
          Printtyp.type_scheme p.pat_type
    | _ -> ()
end

module Iterator = TypedtreeIter.MakeIterator(MyIteratorArgument)
```

Module type `TypedtreeIter.IteratorArgument` is to specify what your iterator does for each AST construct. You have two points to execute your job: when the traversal enters a construct and when it exits from it. For `pattern`, for example, you have `enter_pattern` and `exit_pattern`. You do not need to worry about the recursion traversal itself: it is the job of the functor `MakeIterator`. Giving an `IteratorArgument` module it wires up all the `enter_*` and `exit_*` recursively and returns a module with bunch of iterators.

Normally you are interested only in some part of AST and want to skip the others. `DefaultIteratorArgument` is a module whose `enter_*` and `exit_*` do nothing. Your `IteratorArgument` module should include `DefaultIteratorArgument` to inherit this default behaviour, then implement only the parts which do something special.

If you want not only to traverse typed ASTs but also to modify some part of them, use `TypedtreeMap` instead of `TypedtreeIter`. There is a small example of `TypedtreeMap` at https://bitbucket.org/camlspotter/compiler-libs-hack/src/340072a7c14cbce624b98a57bf8c4c6509c40a31/overload/mod.ml?at=default.

(I do not use ocamlbuild, so I cannot help that point.)

Comment: Hi, @camlspotter, thanks for the great example! The `TypedtreeIter` is neat! One thing I think is missing the iterator functor does not provide current `Env` we are in. So we may not be able to track a variable's definition site. Have you met the problem before and know other utility functions in the code base solving this?

Comment: Each typed AST node has the type environment which was used to build the node.

Answer (score 3):

OCaml provides its own compiler as a library named `compiler-libs`. It has everything in it, allowing one to move from a concrete syntax towards executable, with all intermidiate steps under your control, including typedtree, of course.

The bad news is that it is not documented. I would suggest you, to use `utop` or `merlin` to explore this library.

You do not need anything special to do with ocamlbuild to use `compiler-libs`, it is a regular library.

Comment: Hi, @ivg Thanks for the reply. Before I dive into the source code, one quick question is that does this library exposes APIs for a whole OCaml project processing? Or due to OCaml's great support for separate compilation, the problem of typing whole project reduces to typing each files one by one? Thanks.

Comment: as far as I understand it exposes only the compiler part, so that you can build your own driver using the libraries. If you really need to take ocaml project and compile it with your own tweaked compiler, then it would be easier just to tweak the compiler. But for testing, and investigation, compiler is still a good choice.