# Traverse typed abstract syntax tree in Haskell Compiler

Tags: haskell, compiler-construction, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm trying to dump type information of all identifiers in an Haskell project, basically it's the same as traversing the typed abstract syntax tree.

From [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28389568/how-to-traverse-typed-abstract-syntax-tree-in-ocaml-compiler), OCaml exposes its internal APIs through a library called `compiler-libs`. I'm wondering how is Haskell's support for similar task?

Comment: Unfortunately GHC does not expose a nice API for this.  You might get some milage from [haskell-type-exts](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/haskell-type-exts).

Answer (score 1):

[GHC-as-a-library](https://wiki.haskell.org/GHC/As_a_library) gives you a `TypecheckedModule`, and `getNamesInScope`, which includes the type of each name.